# *serious* Confusion about the general solution to equations such as $\sin(9 \theta) = \frac{13}{20}$.

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve things like for example
$$\sin(9 \theta) = \frac{13}{20}$$

Now the solution to $9\theta$ is $\sin^{-1} (13/20) + 2n \pi$, for an integer n.

But why do websites say the general solution for $\sin x$ is $n \pi + (-1)^n \theta$?

[image]

Like, why is one answer got a $n \pi$ and the other has $2n \pi$???

Not making sense.
Please help, it is causing me consternation - please dont be trivial and downvote, this is a serious question that I actually tried think an answer to but I really can't.

Comment: This Q is hard to read. Hence, consider to visit [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for format improvement.

Comment: The sine function is periodic. That means that if you have one solution you can find others that are a period away.

Comment: "...But why do websites say..." : Going forward, with your future MathSE postings, in a similar situation, please provide a link to the source (e.g. website) that you are referring to.  For help managing a link, see the Links section of [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: well that was done

Comment: The general solution to $\sin x=\sin t$ is $$x=t+2\pi n\quad\text{OR}\quad x=(\pi-t)+2\pi n, \quad n\in\Bbb{Z} \tag1$$ The table's author decided to get a little clever, though, observing that we can write this as
$$x=t+\pi\cdot 2n \quad\text{OR}\quad x=-t+\pi\cdot(2n+1)\tag2$$ 
$$x=(-1)^{2n}t+\pi\cdot 2n \quad\text{OR}\quad x=(-1)^{2n+1}t+\pi\cdot(2n+1)\tag3$$
and, finally,
$$x=(-1)^mt+\pi m\tag4$$
which *works*, because even $m=2n$ is covered by the first component of $(3)$, and odd $m=2n+1$ is covered by the second component. Clever, indeed! ... Personally, I just remember $(1)$.

Comment: @blue thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $\sin(x) = a $ has two basic solutions in $[0, 2\pi) $

These are

$ x = \sin^{-1} a $

And

$ x = \pi - \sin^{-1} a $

So the general solutions are

$ x = \sin^{-1} a + 2 n \pi $

and

$ x = \pi - \sin^{-1} a + 2 n \pi = - \sin^{-1} a + (2 n + 1) \pi $

Comment: so why is n=1?/

Comment: I didn't say that $n = 1$.

Comment: if you compare your final line of your answer to the 6th row in my table (above), you will see that the implication is that n=1